# Exception opening socket - MongoDB, Docker

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have Maven Multi-Module application(Spring Boot + MySql + MongoDB) with using docker image, but i can't get connection to MongoDB.

Thing is when local mongo instance "MongoDB Server on Windows Services"  is turned on and use *spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost* all is working fine.

But when I turn off mongo instance and try to go with:
spring.data.mongodb.host=$(MONGO_HOST) to use it with docker I'm getting error *"Exception opening socket"*

I start my application with execute command:
*mvn install* and tryed with *docker-compose up --build*

**console**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.1)

2021-09-25 12:19:22.635  INFO 8588 --- [           main] c.o.o.n.controller.NoteControllerTest    : Starting NoteControllerTest using Java 16.0.1 on AntonioPC with PID 8588 (started by ajago in D:\Programming\Eclipse-workspace\OC_Project10\Notes)
2021-09-25 12:19:22.642  INFO 8588 --- [           main] c.o.o.n.controller.NoteControllerTest    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-09-25 12:19:23.776  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-25 12:19:23.777  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-25 12:19:23.824  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.openclassrooms.ocproject10.notes.repository.NoteRepository. If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: javax.persistence.Entity, javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.
2021-09-25 12:19:23.826  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-09-25 12:19:24.093  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-09-25 12:19:24.094  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-09-25 12:19:24.126  INFO 8588 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 31 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-09-25 12:19:24.876  INFO 8588 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-09-25 12:19:25.458  INFO 8588 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-09-25 12:19:25.596  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-09-25 12:19:25.685  INFO 8588 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-09-25 12:19:25.882  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-09-25 12:19:26.112  INFO 8588 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-09-25 12:19:27.051  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-09-25 12:19:27.065  INFO 8588 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-09-25 12:19:27.486  INFO 8588 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-09-25 12:19:27.586  INFO 8588 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted

2021-09-25 12:19:28.302  WARN 8588 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-09-25 12:19:28.988  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2021-09-25 12:19:28.988  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2021-09-25 12:19:28.990  INFO 8588 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-09-25 12:19:29.018  INFO 8588 --- [           main] c.o.o.n.controller.NoteControllerTest    : Started NoteControllerTest in 7.33 seconds (JVM running for 9.77)
2021-09-25 12:19:29.380  INFO 8588 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  reports:
    image: 'reports:latest'
    build:
      context: ./reports
    container_name: reports
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - PATIENTS_URL=http://gps:8081
      - NOTES_URL=http://rewards:8082
      
  patients:
    image: 'patients:latest'
    build:
      context: ./patients
    container_name: patients
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db-mysql
    depends_on:
      - db-mysql

  notes:
    image: 'notes:latest'
    build:
      context: ./notes
    container_name: notes
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    environment:
      - MONGO_HOST=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      
  db-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    command: --innodb --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: project_10
        MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Musapa1990..        
     
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    network_mode: host
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    environment:
        MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: project_10
```

**application.properties**

```
# App config
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO
spring.application.name=P10_notes
server.port=8082

################### MongoDB Configuration ##########################
spring.data.mongodb.database=project_10
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.host=$(MONGO_HOST)
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin

# thymeleaf configurations for Auto reload Thymeleaf templates without restart
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/
```

I read similar articles here and tried different things, but nothing helped me.

Comment: try replacing the round brackets with curly brackets in this line `spring.data.mongodb.host=$(MONGO_HOST)`

Comment: unfortunately ${MONGO_HOST} didn't help either

Comment: can you try hardcoding the host value? put mongodb in the properties file

Comment: `Connection refused` means the operating system on the destination actively refused the connection because nothing was listening on that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I messed up something when installing mongodb. When I reinstalled the mongo it worked. I did not make any crucial changes in the code.
Only what I added was:

```
################### MongoDB Configuration ##########################
spring.data.mongodb.database=project_10
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

I added that on all 3 module on application.properties because each of modules are using MongoDB.

Comment: This is crazy, because I'm experiencing the same issue. I'm on an M1 Mac, not sure if that makes any difference. I'll post my own question, because this is driving me nuts.

I'm not sure what you "messed up" during installation mongodb, since you're just using a docker image...

Answer (score 0):

If that not work then you can try that

change localhost and 127.0.0.1  it worked for me
like this

```
#spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost  
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
```